# Convert string to date using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: android

I am doing application in android platform.
My application will retrieve date from MySQL  as a string format,
again i am trying  to convert to date format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert String to date you can use SimpleDateFormat's parse function.

```
String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
Date dateObj = sdf.parse(dateStr);
Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance();
myCal.setTime(dateObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

**try**

```
String DateFromDb = "your Date from DB";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");//set format of date you receiving from db
Date date = (Date) sdf.parse(DateFromDb);
SimpleDateFormat newDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");//set format of new date
System.out.println(newDate.format(date));
String ActDate = newDate.format(date);// here is your new date !
```